# check file of sftp and return output to log

Tags: linux, bash, networking, scripting

I need your assistance.
I'm trying to finish a script that I've done but it is not working perfectly.

here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
iclog=log
key="keys/cash_prod_key"
date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
logname="logfile_${date}vendor.log"
file="filename_20190621_vendor"
logdate=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
flag="N"


#REMOVING LOG FILES OLDER THAN 30 DAYS

find $iclog -type f -name "filename_*_vendor.log" -follow -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; -print


#----Log File---------#



#SFTP CHECK

#echo Log BEGIN For $logdate>$iclog/$logname

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1> $iclog/$logname 2>&1


while [ "$flag" != "Y" ]
do
sftp -b - -oPort=6022 user@sftp_host << EOF
ls -la $file
bye
EOF

if [[ -f $file ]]; then
inf_log "File is available on the vendor........."
sftp -b - -oPort=6022 user@sftp_host <<EOF
ls -la $file
bye
EOF
flag='Y'
else
sleep 300
fi
done

#-------Check file availability--------#

grep -q "$file" $iclog/$logname

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        inf_log "File available!"
else
        err " File is not Found!!! - Please call Support ASAP"
        exit 1
fi
```

So when I'm running the script in debug mode I get the following output:

```
$ bash -x ./check.sh
+ iclog=log
+ key=keys/cash_prod_key
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ date=20190623
+ logname=filename_20190623_vendor.log
+ file=filename_20190621_vendor
++ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
+ logdate=20190623062939
+ flag=N
+ find log -type f -name 'filename_*_vendor.log' -follow -mtime +30 -exec rm '{}' ';' -print
+ exec
+ trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
+ exec
```

And stays in this step executing the script, it doesn't advance for the grep in the log file.
from the log file, it seems that even finding the file it sleeps.

Could you please assist me so the file can be checked on the log file and return output for that same log file?

Thank you all

Comment: Shouldn't `f -name "filename_*_vendor.log"` be `f -name $file`? On line 14 as I count it. You defined that (file) on line 7.

Comment: @somebody at line 14 it is a search and delete log files with more than 30 days. It could be define with $logname.

Comment: Right. Sorry. Looking at it again, I see I just misread the output from your run of the script. Looking at it again, just now. I wonder if it might not be a good idea to ensure you always hit the correct directory by either defining `iclog` with a `CWD`. Like `iclog=./log`. Doing so, or using a complete path will make the finished script a bit more flexible, and even *safer*. Should it be executed from another directory that *also* has a `log` subdir`, or maybe just a *file* named `log`. :)